# Can "please" be used a lot in writing?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am currently developing a software with my team. After reviewing all the texts in the product, I noticed that we use the word "please" a lot.
Some examples:

- Please take a look at the documentation to see how to connect a new domain.
- Please fill this form...

Is this a bad habit?

Thanks

Comment: It's best not to overuse any word.

Comment: Please don't ask POB questions about "writing style".

Comment: "Please" is good to use in connection with a request that someone else take some action.  That way everyone (including those whose native language is not English) will know that it is a request.  I say, if all of them are like your two samples, keep the "please"s.

Comment: @GEdgar Alright thanks for your clear answer. We will keep this habit then.
FumbleFingers I have no idea what you mean...

Comment: In English "software" is not countable (unlike program) i.e. "I am developing software", not "a software". If you need to refer to more than one program, you should say something like "two pieces of software" or make it an adjective — "two software applications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use the word “please” as many times as you want as long as it’s in a personal letter to Santa Claus, a song or a poem. Otherwise over use may cause problems with redundancy and clarity.

Comment: Still giving you a thumbs up. Maybe suggest some ways to reduce the instances. For example, put one "please" at the start of a list of requested items. "Please do each of the following:" followed by the list. Or put one "please" at the start of an instructional memo. "Please follow the guidance in this memo."  Or if it's a formal instructional document, dispense with "please" completely. "All staff are required to follow the policies on respectful behavior."

Answer (score 0):

If the texts have been written by different members of the team, then the chances are that you will need to edit them. If you want a consistent product, you need one consistent style, which is unlikely from a team effort.

My feeling is that if, when read together, there are too many uses of 'Please', edit the uses down to a level that seems appropriate for the product.